# Cannot execute dotnet app as daemon service

Tags: c#, .net, linux, daemon

I'm trying to run my `dotnet` application as a daemon service, the first steps that I did are:

1. Created the application using `NetCore 2.0`
2. Build the binary using `dotnet publish bot`

inside `Ubuntu` terminal I created an user for run the daemon:

```
sudo useradd -s /sbin/nologin dotnetuser
sudo mkdir /var/bot
sudo cp -R /home/publish/* /var/bot
sudo chown -R dotnetuser:dotnetuser /var/bot
```

so I created a custom `systemd` unit file under: `/etc/systemd/system/netcore-console-bot.service` directory:

```
[Unit]
Description= Bot console application
DefaultDependencies = no

[Service]
Type = oneshot
RemainAfterExit = no
ExecStart= /var/bot/ bot.dll
WorkingDirectory = /var/bot
User = dotnetuser
Group = dotnetuser

[install]
```

I tried to execute the `daemon` using the `systemctl status` command: `start netcore-console-bot.service`

but I got:

> netcoreconsole-bot.service: Main process exited, code=exit

What I did wrong?

Comment: Publish from *where* and targeting which OS? This error complains about the binary file itself. You'd get this error if you compiled for Windows and tried to run on Linux, or compiled for x64 and tried to run on x86

Comment: Error indicates that you are trying to start a service without starting CLR

Comment: Have you already reviewed https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/06/07/writing-a-linux-daemon-in-c/

Comment: Can you run the executable directly with `dotnet path/to/the.dll` ?

Comment: Maybe that's because unnecessary space in your ExecStart section?

Comment: I mean that space between `/var/bot/` and  `bot.dll`.

Comment: Well that means this problem is now solved and you have another one (and for new one you can consult logs mentioned in error message).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the only change that you need to make from my testing is making sure to tell dotnet to run the dll. My paths should be pretty close to what you need to do. Alternatively you could use a [self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) when you publish and package the runtime with the app.

```
[Unit]
Description= Bot console application
DefaultDependencies = no

[Service]
Type = oneshot
RemainAfterExit = no
ExecStart= /usr/bin/dotnet /var/bot/bot.dll
WorkingDirectory = /var/bot
User = dotnetuser
Group = dotnetuser

[install]
```